# "No rule to make target" error during building in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, makefile, ubuntu-16.04

I am new to Linux (so I aplogize if this seems too obvious), and I have installed a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 version. I am trying to compile and install "the Director" repository from github (https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/director). After typing `make superbuild`, after a while I get this error:

`make[6]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so', needed by 'lib/libvtkDRCFilters.so'.  Stop.`

I noticed there is no `libSM.so` inside `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` but I quickly searched for similar files and I founde these two:

```
gian@gian-K54C:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ ls libSM.so.*
libSM.so.6  libSM.so.6.0.1
```

Any idea on how to solve this? Thanks

EDIT: apparently `libSM.so` exists inside `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`, though I didn't see it in the first instance. It's even more confusing now...

Comment: Please include info on how to reproduce it like name of software and what is the command you are running when the error occur

Comment: @dlmeetei I added some details, as you suggested

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so
```

Comment: Ok, I tried that but I get: `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so': File exists`

Comment: And I checked again, and now I see `libSM.so` inside `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. So the file is in there... I am even more confused now

Comment: Are you sure you're building in the right directory?

Comment: What is the output of `pwd`?

Comment: It is not failing at linking, It is complaining that there is no rule for the target

Comment: @dlmeetei No rule for the target could be a result of the file not existing. the symlink was to make sure the library exists for the compiler.

Comment: @dlmeetei Look at the question again. "I noticed there is no libSM.so inside /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ "

Comment: This might be a stupid thing, but if I type `ls` inside `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, the `libSM.so` file is the only one which is highlighted in red. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @GianlucaJohnMassimiani What is the output of `ls -l`?

Comment: @dlmeetei Look at the edit time and my answer time :)

Comment: Red on `libSM.so` means link is broken.

Comment: Output of `ls -l ` is: `lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        20 lug 30 12:53 libSM.so -> /usr/lib/libSM.6.0.1`

Comment: @GianlucaJohnMassimiani That's the problem do the following: `rm -f /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so` and try linking again.

Comment: @Samy I get `Permission denied`

Comment: @dlmeetei How very mature :)

Comment: @Samy Ok, that worked! I have now the same problem with another file, but I'll fix it in the same way. Thanks a lot!